# Expo modules for reactnative 0.65 bare project

Tags: react-native, expo

How can I install expo modules for bare reactnative 0.65 project? I tried to install but I am getting java11 error. I cannot upgrade java since 0.65 requires java8.

Comment: what is your current java version

Comment: java 8 since 0.65 requires this version